# Why isn't the flex-grow property changing anything?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Container div is display flex, but the two child divs do not respond to the flex grow property.This approach seemed to work fine for li's in a ul, what am I doing wrong?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .featured {
  background: pink;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container .loaded {
  background: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="featured">
    <h2>Featured Article</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum ihsjrtop fdiubhreg urfhga ergujdfhjbsd fmbn szlriuv vfduvbhl;er vkl.ifhb;oabe rvkdbfvjsh fvnz dfbvzlh g;oiuhv za,rujhvblzubjavznbmsdf v vjlzUBvmzBSv blizU vzUIJBVl;djhb mzcn dvz,bdfrvmzn dcv,zubdfvmn zfv,uzjbdfkbvjnv.zbin.d,vjbnkd bvnzfbzdj
      v,jzdfuvblkjdfg ,fdjknb;oizdf b.kfzdnbizd fvbkjzfdb vf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="loaded">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will work if you use `flex:` instead of  `flex-grow:`**

For more details, you better read this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Note:** *`flex` is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional.*

In here I have used:

`flex: 1;` = `flex-grow: 1;flex-shrink: 1;flex-basis: 0%;`

`flex: 3;` = `flex-grow: 3;flex-shrink: 1;flex-basis: 0%;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .featured {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
}

.container .loaded {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="featured">
    <h2>Featured Article</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum ihsjrtop fdiubhreg urfhga ergujdfhjbsd fmbn szlriuv vfduvbhl;er vkl.ifhb;oabe rvkdbfvjsh fvnz dfbvzlh g;oiuhv za,rujhvblzubjavznbmsdf v vjlzUBvmzBSv blizU vzUIJBVl;djhb mzcn dvz,bdfrvmzn dcv,zubdfvmn zfv,uzjbdfkbvjnv.zbin.d,vjbnkd bvnzfbzdj
      v,jzdfuvblkjdfg ,fdjknb;oizdf b.kfzdnbizd fvbkjzfdb vf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="loaded">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: The `flex: 1` equals `flex-grow: 1;flex-shrink: 1;flex-basis: 0` ... note, no unit on _flex-basis_